# Expect jasmine test spec to time out

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, assertion

Is there a way to expect for a jasmine test spec to fail due to timeout? Something like

```js
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = TEN_SECONDS;

it('expect to time out', () => {
  function loops_Forever() {while (true);}
  expect(loops_Forever).toTimeOut();
});
```